# map something to the action of the leader key?

Tags: key-bindings, search, leader

I have this in my vimrc:

```
let g:mapleader = ","
nnoremap # ,
```

so I use , as my leader, and want to use # for backwards search after f,t...But my # mapping does not work, so something is amiss

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To set your leader key, you must use `let mapleader = ","` not `let g:mapleader = ","`.

From `:h <leader>`

```
                    *<Leader>* *mapleader*
To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special string
"<Leader>" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value of "mapleader".
If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.  Example: >
    :map <Leader>A  oanother line<Esc>
Works like: >
    :map \A  oanother line<Esc>
But after: >
    :let mapleader = ","
It works like: >
    :map ,A  oanother line<Esc>
```

As for using `nnoremap <something> <leader>` like you did, this causes no issues for me. Make sure you don't have some other mapping by running the command: `nnoremap ,`. It should print `No mapping found`.